# Change Alert Function to Show Div on JavaScript form validation?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a way of changing the alert function on my script to show my div 'error' instead, can someone please show me how i may do this? thanks

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
 First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function validateForm()
 {
 var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
 if (x==null || x=="")
   {
   alert("First name must be filled out");
   return false;
   }
 }
```

i have tried:

```
function validateForm()
 {
 var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
 if (x==null || x=="")
   {
   show("error");
   return false;
   }
 }
```

error css:

```
.error{
width: 946px;
margin: auto;
height: 20px;
overflow: hidden;
font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
padding:20px;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
border: 1px solid #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
background-color:#FF9933 ;
margin-bottom:30px;
display: none

}
```

Comment: `show()` is an jQuery function, do you have included jQuery?

Comment: is there a `<div>` with `id=error` on your html that you have hidden and want to show, or you want it created just for validation purposes? Also, as R3tep said, are yu using jQuery or just plain javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/vihup/1/edit)

Just Add div tag in your html page like the following with the css class which you have specified.

```
   <div id ="alertBox" class="error">
    ERROR
  </div>
```

Just Add the following line in the javascript.

```
document.getElementById("alertBox").style.display='block';
```

Comment: thanks this worked, also is there anyway i can make the script echo out the errors in the form? e.g. fname was not completed etc

Comment: @JohnTaylor : This is very basic example. To fine tune the performance, We can do it in some other ways. But Idea is the same. (Still your code has many bugs - How you going to close the custom message box)

Answer (score 0):

for jquery:

```
$("#error").css({ // if "error" is a class use: $(".error").css({
    display:'block'
});
```